# Postback inside update panel issue

Tags: c#, updatepanel, postback

I have a panel inside an update panel that is initially hidden. When a row inside a grid is selected this panel is made visible with details of selected record.

In this panel I have a dropdown list that does a postback in order to set the text of a label. When postback happens, the panel is made invisible again. I tried setting triggers for update panel and set it to dropdown's slectedindexchanged event but didn't work. I put this update panel inside another update panel but no luck.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlDetail" RenderMode="Inline">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlDetail" style="display:none">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                ID="ddlIDSID" 
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                DataSourceID="odsIDS" 
                DataTextField="IDSNAME_BK" 
                DataValueField="IDSID" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIDSID_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIDSSite" CssClass="NormalSmall" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When grid is selected, I use javascript to populate the controls and make the panel visible:

```
function populate(record) {
    var oDetailPanel = document.getElementById('<%=pnlDetail.ClientID %>');
    /* set up all controls  */
    oDetailPanel.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: In your ddlIDSID_SelectedIndexChanged method in C#, set the panel to visible.

Comment: I tried that too. But because the the controls in the details section are populated client side, using JavaScript, making panel visible in selectedindexchanged only updates the drop down and its associated label and clears all other controls.

Comment: I could not get this to work when I populate the details controls client side. I changed to server side control population and got rid of the issue. It is not as smooth of a transition when different records are selected from the grid but have no choice at the moment. I still would love to know if this is doable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially solve your issue on the Page Load, of your call:

```
if(Page.IsPostback)
     pnContent.Visible = true;
```

You may have to do the `IsAjaxPostBack` I think it is through the Script Manager.

Below is why I'm against Update Panel's.

---

In short, while still using an *Update Panel*, this problem will be *very* complicated to fix. You should use your own Ajax instead.

The issue itself is quite common.  The *Hypertext Transfer Protocol* is stateless, but *Asp.Net Web-Forms* creates an entire life cycle that immediately forces some form of state persistence to your application.

One of the tools to help alleviate some of those pressures is the notoriously evil *Update Panel*.  This panel isn't anything special, it simply copies your entire page to memory, then executes the *Postback* via Ajax to hit the server without the *flicker* that will occur when you normally do a *Postback*.

*Update Panel Issues*:

- Performance heavy.
- Difficult to debug or ensure works correctly.
- Hard to gauge page state.

The third point is the most prevalent for one singular reason, it makes you code in a circle.  What I'm trying to say, your page loads.  The *Update Panel* triggers, page refreshes.  The page is modified via the client, *Update Panel* triggers, page refreshes without Client-Side modification.

> The server isn't aware of your Client-Side change, it doesn't persist
>   in memory.  So when the *Update Panel* triggers it recalls the page
>   from the last moment the server sent data.

The only way to truly fix this. You have to implement `QueryStrings` and other nuances to help ensure the *Server-Side* and *Client-Side* stay in synchronization.  This will create spaghetti incredibly quick, so hopefully you enjoy pasta.

The best way to avoid these scenarios, is to leverage *Web Services* and send your own *Ajax* to ensure the page always reflects the goal, so when your user does a *Postback*, you are in control of the data sent.

Hopefully this explanation explains in detail the pitfalls of using an *Update Panel*. More than likely redoing the page in the manner I mentioned above will be far faster unless you can avoid *JavaScript* and rely solely on the server.

I'm trying to truly convey why you should use your own Ajax and do it yourself without having data applied automatically through the *Update Panel*.  You **shouldn't** use the panel, should do it yourself.

Comment: Add web services overcomplicates this problem greatly. Update panels have been successfully used in many applications for years.

Comment: The fact that they can be used doesn't imply that they should be used. They're a hacky shortcut. If what you need is a hacky shortcut, and you understand the consequences, then go ahead. If you need something clean, performant and maintainable, then avoid them. Once they're in there, they're quite hard to replace.

Comment: @David Update Panel I'm assuming?

Comment: Yep. UpdatePanels are like Netbooks. There was a time for them, which lasted about a year or two, at most.